# Auto update Excel databse

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 2007. I have an Excel file that has cell A1 showing a date and cell B1 showing an amount in sheet 1. I need to automatically update the date in A1 and amount B1 in a database in sheet 2. The database in sheet 2 is link to cell A1 and B1 in sheet 1 by using Vlookup by choosing the date in A1 as the lookup value. The excel file is use on a daily basis and cell A1 and B1 content will change daily. Sheet 2 will need to record all the dates and amount in cell A1 and B1 for one year

My problem :
1. How do i build my database to capture the previous date and amount in A1 and B1 daily because the dates in A1 keep changing as it is key in on a daily basis.

For example :-

On 14/3/2015 (cell A1) figure is $3,333 in cell B1. Hence the data base captures the date 14/3/2015 and $3,333 in sheet 2 in the database.

On the following day,15/3/2015, cell A1 content is now changed to 15/3/2015 and B1 shows a figure of $5,555

My challenge is how do I keep both dates and value in sheet 2 in my database since I can only get one date and value for the current day only.

Honestly I dont know VBA.

Comment: **What causes the data in A1 and B1 to change??**

Answer (score 1):

This is made only slightly more tricky because you want to copy over two cells. Typically, you can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to catch whenever a cell changes. However, you want to wait until both cells have changed. Rather than enforce some rule where you have to change them in the right order and then just watching the last cell, I wrote this to wait for cell `C1` to change instead. My thought was that your users can edit `A1` & `B1` then then type *anything* in `C1` and the code would fire. You could use Data Validation to add a drop-down to `C1` that only has one option like "Go". The code below will copy the values of `A1` & `B1` to the last row in sheet 2 whenever the value of `C1` is changed and then clear that value from `C1`.

Open the VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> is one method). Look for sheet 1 in the Project Explorer window on the left (it should already be there with a tree menu showing all open workbooks and the worksheets within them). Double-click on the sheet to open its code window. Copy and paste the code below: (You may have to edit line `Worksheets("Sheet2")` if "Sheet2" isn't the actual name of your second worksheet to which you want the data copied.)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Long
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            r = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & r).Value = Range("A1").Value
            .Range("B" & r).Value = Range("B1").Value
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("C1").ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

(To the VBA junkies out there: I typically prefer using `Cells` over `Range` but it's not as instantly understandable so I went with `Range`.)

Comment: Good explanation *(+1)*

Answer (score -1):

If you do not know and cannot learn the tools to do the job, your only alternative is to do it manually.

Then write down the steps you had to do manually - that will be your outline for how to automate it.

Then start Googling how to create a simple VBA macro that will automate the steps you wrote down.